# Linux/cmake: How can I make the linker tell me where it looked?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

Say I'm compiling some really complicated project with millions of lines of code. It fails due to not being able to find (some) libraries (.h or .so files), using code like:

```
#include <mymodule/mylibrary.h>
```

How can I, in readable output, make the linker tell me where it looked for a library?
I'd like a list of directories/paths, instead of just `no such file or directory`, with no clue as to why.

Also I'd like it to be very clear about slashes at the end... I'd hate to overlook a double slash in the *actual* path and end up wasting hours searching for the problem in other places if at all possible.

Comment: Might want to clean up the terminology a bit because the question is a bit confused. The linker has nothing to do with include directives. Those are handled by the compiler, and if they're wrong, you don't get to the linking stage (unless you also have a mistake in your build system). You need to separately tell the linker where to look and what to look for.

Comment: just look at the compiler / linker commands in full. E.g., if cmake is using ninja, and your build is at `out/build/gcc-debug`, then `cmake --build out/build/gcc-debug -v`, which passes the `-v` flag for "verbose" to ninja. And then you can see what the underlying compiles/links are doing, e.g. `-I` for include paths, etc

Comment: Since you've mentioned cmake, as a start, have you checked `compile_commands.json`?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=gcc+print+search+paths+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: "not being able to find (some) libraries (.h or .so files)" - Where to find includes (for the compiler (.h files)) and where to find libraries (for the linker (.so files)) is two very different things. Can you create a [mre] perhaps?

Comment: "no such file or directory, with no clue as to why" - Ehh, the reason in that case is *obvious*; the file did not exist. What more do you want the tool to tell you? How could the tool possibly know *why* the file did not exist where you told it to find it?

Comment: You might want to mention which toolchain (gcc, clang, MSVC, etc.) you are using to compile. There is no guarantee that all toolchains use the same command line options to produce more information. (Tagging cmake is potentially good, but I don't know if that provides a cross-toolchain option for this.)

Comment: I don't understand the double slash comment in the question. In linux multiple slashes are exactly the same as a single slash. `/home/aphid/`,`//home/aphid///` are refering to exactly the same folder, and `-L /usr/lib` and `-L /usr/lib/` and `-L/usr/lib//` are also exactly equivalent linker options.